# Line Spacing Issues when Exporting to Powerpoint (pptx) from Google Slides

Tags: google-slides

I exported a Google Slides presentation to Powerpoint (pptx). I then opened it using Microsoft Powerpoint Viewer. Unfortunately, the line spacing of the text boxes appear too spaced out. I didn't define a spacing, I used the default 1.15. My font is Tahoma 18-20. Changing the line spacing/font or setting a custom line-spacing has no affect on the text when opened in Microsoft Powerpoint presentation.

Upon further instigation, it appears that bullets from lists have gone as well. This leads me to believe that bulleted lists aren't being exported correctly to Powerpoint from Google Slides.

Has anyone else come across this problem and if so, does anyone know a way to prevent/rectify the problem?